# julia: Using an index identifier twice in a nested for

Tags: for-loop, scope, julia, identifier, scoping

By accident I used the same counter twice in a nested for loop:

```
for i in 1:2
    println(i)
    for j in 1:2
        for i in 5:6
            i += 1
            println(i, " ", j)
        end
    end
end
```

Which compiled without issue, and produced

```
1
6 1
7 1
6 2
7 2
2
6 1
7 1
6 2
7 2
```

It took me by surprise once I realized what was going on. Is this behavior intended? Since this leads to unexpected behavior, is there any way to make the compiler flag this as an error?

Just as an example, Fortran throws an error when compiling similar code:

```
program testfor

integer :: i, j, k

do i = 1,2
    do j = 1,2
        do i = 5,6
            i = i+1
            write(*,*) i, j
        end do
    end do
end do

end program testfor
```

Save as `ftest.f90`, then compiling with `$:gfortran ftest.f90 -o ftest` shows two errors:

```
ftest.f90:7:18:

    5 | do i = 1,2
      |          2        
    6 |     do j = 1,2
    7 |         do i = 5,6
      |                  1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
ftest.f90:8:19:

    7 |         do i = 5,6
      |                  2 
    8 |             i = i+1
      |                   1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
```

Comment: Would a linter help? This is called variable shadowing; it's bad practice, and it's permitted in many languages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about that. There seems to be an Atom addon for this, that interfaces with the package`StaticLint.jl`. There is no clear usage example, but I can tinker around with it, https://atom.io/packages/linter-julia , https://github.com/julia-vscode/StaticLint.jl

Comment: I assumed this would behave as described for "soft scope" in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope , but I notice it says "global variable `x`" specifically there - I had just assumed it would apply whenever there's an outer `x` (or `i` in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** yes, it is fully intended and absolutely reasonable and consistent.

**Long answer:** There are two things going on in your code that result in the observed behavior, and which are worth pointing out.

1. Name shadowing (as also mentioned in the comments above). There are in fact three separate variables here, two of which happened to be called `i`. And while the inner `i` is within scope, there is no way to access the outer `i`.
2. Range loops. From the way you have written your code, I assume you expect this sort of `for` loop to run as it would in C, for example: let's have a loop variable, which is incremented in every cycle. At least the explicit extra increment in your innermost loop suggests this. In Julia, however, for loops *iterate over iterable objects*, in this case, the `Range` object. And the most important part: the current state of the iteration is stored in a hidden variable. The value of the variable you iterate with has absolutely no affect on the state. Therefore, neither incrementing `i` explicitly has an effect on the state of the inner loop, nor shadowing `i` has an effect on the state of the outer loop. Both loops keep chugging along the predetermined ranges.